# Arquillian test is failing, don't understand error

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to learn Java EE with WildFly and Maven. I am trying to follow a tutorial, but I am stuck on a part on testing. Unfortunately, the tutorial jumps around a bit so I don't get all of the information. Every time I run the test, I get the follow error. Can someone explain what this error is and how I can fix it?

```
  Running com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository.BookRepositoryTest
    Aug 04, 2018 11:09:45 AM org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl resolveArguments
    WARNING: Argument 2 for ArquillianServiceDeployer.doServiceDeploy is null. It won't be invoked.
    Aug 04, 2018 11:09:45 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
    INFO: XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
    Aug 04, 2018 11:09:45 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
    INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
    Aug 04, 2018 11:09:45 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
    INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
    Aug 04, 2018 11:09:48 AM org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer undeploy
    WARN: Cannot undeploy: test.war
    org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper$ServerDeploymentException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: C
    ould not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper.undeploy(ServerDeploymentHelper.java:109)
            at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.undeploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:111)
            at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.undeploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:242)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$4.call(ContainerDeployController.java:205)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$4.call(ContainerDeployController.java:185)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.undeploy(ContainerDeployController.java:184)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$2.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:119)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$2.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:110)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:249)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.undeployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:109)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:108)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.afterClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:94)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3$1.evaluate(Arquillian.java:224)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:219)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:167)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:114)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentMana
    ger.java:50)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.AbstractServerDeploymentManager.execute(AbstractServerDeploymentManager.java:79)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper.undeploy(ServerDeploymentHelper.java:106)
            ... 83 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed
            at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:122)
            at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:257)
            at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:71)
            at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:212)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:146)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:65)
            at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:147)
            at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:122)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:263)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:168)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:111)
            ... 86 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
            at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$ConnectHandle.handleReady(WorkerThread.java:319)
            at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:559)
            at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:294)
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:275)
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:379)
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:367)
            at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connect(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:83)
            at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:114)
            ... 96 more

    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.463 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository.BookRepositoryTest
    com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository.BookRepositoryTest  Time elapsed: 5.462 sec  <<< ERROR!
    org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: test.war
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

    Aug 04, 2018 11:09:48 AM org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl resolveArguments
    WARNING: Argument 2 for ArquillianServiceDeployer.undeploy is null. It won't be invoked.

    Results :

    Tests in error:
      BookRepositoryTest.com.pluralsight.bookstore.repository.BookRepositoryTest » Deployment

    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183287#focus=streamItem-27-2985713-0-0 could be the case.

Comment: The management client doesn't seem to be able to connect to the server. Check the log files for the server to see if there is an error in there.

Comment: Please show your arquillian.xml!